# Unchecking a checkbox, but the attribute remains checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox with a default checked="checked".

If I uncheck the checkbox however, and then do something like

```
alert($('#checkbox').attr('checked'));
```

Regardless of whether it is checked or not, it will always alert `checked`.

[**I've made a codepen of this functionality over here**](http://codepen.io/robertnorth/pen/qanie).

How do I go about getting the actual checked status of a checkbox (and not what was written in the default code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`attr` is bound to the DOM attribute and then remains to the initial value. If you want to check the state, you have to use `prop` instead :

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')
```

For more information, you can read the paragraph "Attributes vs. Properties" of the jQuery doc for [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 5):

Using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead since:

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a
>   boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if
>   the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute
>   has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is
>   true of all boolean attributes.

```
alert($('#checkbox').prop('checked'));
```

Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 3):

The actual checked status is stored in the `checked` property, so use the `.prop()` function:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
alert($('#checkbox').prop('checked'));
```

You'll get `true` or `false`

To get more information about attr vs prop check the official [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) documentation, in particular, section **Attributes vs. Properties**

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is true of all boolean attributes.
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property:
>
> if ( elem.checked )
>
> if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
>
> if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )
>
> The same is true for other dynamic attributes, such as selected and value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the is function in jquery to check, this will give true or false

```
$('#checkbox').is(':checked')
```

See this fix to your code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mHqAI

Comment: Actually that will give `false` every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to hear someone's explanation for WHY this happens, but I'll show you what I've always done to fix it

```
$('#checkbox').get(0).checked
```

I'm using the native dom's interpretation of whether or not the checkbox is actually checked, and so long as #checkbox exists, this works perfectly

Comment: There's a separation between attributes and properties; when the DOM is constructed from HTML it takes the values for the attributes and sets the corresponding properties. After that it tracks the state using the property, and the attribute isn't updated to reflect changes to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without jQuery:

```
 alert(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kjyAI)